# What is the difference between "as though" and "as if"?

Tags: grammar, differences

I'm genuinely in confusion when it comes to using those two: can I draw a distintive line in using them?

Thank you.

Comment: related [Analogy: "as if" vs. "as though"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134575/analogy-as-if-vs-as-though)

Answer (score 1):

There is no real difference between them and if there is, it is too subtle in common speech. consider the examples below:

"He acted as if he owned everything around me."

"He acted as though he owned everything around me."

The slight difference I mentioned, is that "as if" is used or preferred in speculative cases where you are not confident about something being the reason or cause or fact. In the sentence "he behaved as if he had lost his mind," the phrase "as if" suggests what could have been the cause of the weird demeanor. But if we say "he behaved as though he had lost his mind," it suggests that we have a modicum of confidence on what might have caused that misdemeanor.

But, like I said earlier, this difference matters nada colloquially. Also, we use "as if" sarcastically in some situations.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've never made even that subtle distinction; as far as I can tell, I use and hear "as though" and "as if" completely interchangeably. (Except when using "As if!" sarcastically, like @vickyace mentioned, as a stand-alone sentence fragment. I've never heard "As though!" used this way, and I would be very surprised if I did.)