# I felt as if he was about to say ...?

Tags: meaning

Is this usage of "felt" properly?

Ex: I felt as if he was about to say "I love you".

Comment: Do you mean I felt *as if* or I felt ______?  Please take a moment to [tour] the site and visit the [help].  If you are looking for a [single word request](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info), please provide more information.

Comment: @livresque, I forgot the _if_. I've edited the question. Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate: [Analogy: “as if” vs. “as though”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134575/analogy-as-if-vs-as-though)

Comment: I don't think we have a duplication here. As a portuguese speaker, I was afraid of a literal translation and misuse of the verb _feel_ in the sentence. _Is this usage of "felt" properly?_Overall, by the topic you've provided, it seems fine to use though.

Comment: Yes, the usage of "feel" in that sense is OK.